# Troubles configuring SAML authentication using reverse proxy

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I've developed a small Java application as Service Provider to test the SAML authentication.

The archtecture is: front-end managed by apache (for Angular FE but now is not important) exposed on port 81, back-end managed by wildfly with spring boot + spring security application deployed into exposed on port 8080.

I used okta as Identity Provider

This is my SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository;

@Value("${spring.websecurity.debug:false}")
boolean webSecurityDebug;

@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.debug(webSecurityDebug);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests(authorize -> 
            authorize.antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).saml2Login();

    // add auto-generation of ServiceProvider Metadata
    Converter<HttpServletRequest, RelyingPartyRegistration> relyingPartyRegistrationResolver = new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(relyingPartyRegistrationRepository);
    Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(relyingPartyRegistrationResolver, new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());
    http.addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class);
}


@Bean
protected RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrations2() throws Exception {
    File verificationKey = new File("/somethingpath/okta.cert");
    X509Certificate certificate = X509Support.decodeCertificate(verificationKey);
    Saml2X509Credential credential = Saml2X509Credential.verification(certificate);
    RelyingPartyRegistration registration = RelyingPartyRegistration
            .withRegistrationId("okta-saml")
            .assertingPartyDetails(party -> party
                .entityId("http://www.okta.com/exk8bcocg4Dq....") //oktaid
                .singleSignOnServiceLocation("https://dev-659....okta.com/app/dev-65946316_my_app/exk8bcocg.../sso/saml")
                .wantAuthnRequestsSigned(false)
                .verificationX509Credentials(c -> c.add(credential))
            ).build();
    return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(registration);
}
```

If I configure okta to use General Single Sign On URL/Recipient URL/Destination URL

as     http://hostname:8080/contextroot/login/saml2/sso/okta-saml

and the Audience Restriction (the endpoint of my SP metadata)
as http://hostname:8080/contextroot/saml2/service-provider-metadata/okta-saml

all works. I send the request to okta and after login my SP receive and parse the Response Assertion.

My SP metadata is this

```
 <EntityDescriptor entityID="http://hostname:8080/contextroot/saml2/service-provider-metadata/okta-saml">
<md:SPSSODescriptor WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="**http://hostname:8080/contextroot/login/saml2/sso/okta-saml**" index="1"/>
</md:SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

But I have a requirement: the redirect must not point to wildfly port but to apache port.

So, I configured apache with a reverse proxy in this way

```
    ProxyPass           /PORTCAN/api/ http://hostname:8080/contextroot/ timeout=300
ProxyPassReverse    /PORTCAN/api/ http://hostname:8080/contextroot/ timeout=300
```

and the     General Single Sign On URL/Recipient URL/Destination URL

as     http://hostname:81/PORTCAN/api/login/saml2/sso/okta-saml

In this way I have an error when the response incoming after the login is parsed.
I enabled the spring security log but they are not exaustive

> 2023-02-13 17:36:19,174 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (default task-21)
> Securing POST /login/saml2/sso/okta-saml 2023-02-13 17:36:19,175 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]
> (default task-21) Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
> 2023-02-13 17:36:19,189 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider]
> (default task-21) Processing SAML response from
> http://www.okta.com/exk8bcocg... 2023-02-13 17:36:19,206 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider]
> (default task-21) Validating 1 assertions 2023-02-13 17:36:19,209
> DEBUG
> **[org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.OpenSamlAuthenticationProvider]
> (default task-21) Found 2 validation errors in SAML response
> [id151023229724481221794016439]** 2023-02-13 17:36:19,209 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher]
> (default task-21) No event was found for the exception
> org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.authentication.Saml2AuthenticationException
> 2023-02-13 17:36:19,210 DEBUG
> [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy] (default
> task-21) Redirecting to /contexroot/login?error

My suspect is that he finds some kind of conflict with the new sp metadata
because the "Location" attribute is different by the real General Single Sign On URL/Recipient URL/Destination URL

One is http://hostname:8080/contextroot/login/saml2/sso/okta-saml (SP)
the other is http://hostname:81/PORTCAN/api/login/saml2/sso/okta-saml (on OKTA)

The metadata is autogenerated and I don't know how to change programmatically the location attribute even supposing that this is the cause.

Any suggest?

Thanks in advance